Is there a way to backup/clone 3 drives onto a single drive without ending up with 3 different partitions on Arch Linux?
I have 3 very old hdds that are all lacking and are at least 12 years old. I know you can use a Tool like dd to clone a drive bit by bit, but only if there exists a free partition for it. I want to consolidate all of the data on those drives to a single one without having it all split up again.
I don't mind partitioning during the process, but would like to end up without them in the very end.
The capacities of the old drives are 2,2 and 6 TiB, and the new drive has 12 TiB. The old ones are all roughly half full.
I have both Windows 10 in dual Boot, should I need something from it
Thank you!
Edited to clear up some questions:
These old drives generally are in working conditions, altough at least one of them is showing signs of faliure, but still works and doesn't give out wrong data.
So far the old ones are all formatted to NTFS, as they were used on a Windows System. As for the destination I don't really have a preference, altough BTRFS or NTFS would be nice, as they can be accessed from my Windows Boot, should I ever need it.
as started in the original Post body I would like those three drives to be merged to the single one drive, with the optimum result being that I don't know what was on which original drive.

You say you want all three source drives' data to be merged into a single destination, so that "I don't know what was on which original drive". This supposes that you've given thought to duplicate file paths between the different sources. Let's assume there are no duplicates.
The process I'd use is this, as root,

mount the destination drive/partition, formatted appropriately, on something like /mnt/dst
mount the first source drive/partition on something like /mnt/src
Copy the data from the source to the destination, rsync -rt /mnt/src/ /mnt/dst (This can be interrupted and/or repeated as many times as necessary. Add the -iv flags for extra interest)
Unmount the source disk, umount /mnt/src
Repeat from step 2 with the next disk, and again with the third

At this point all the destination files will be owned by root. If you want to change the ownership then the command would be something like this (but be aware that it may not work for an NTFS filesystem)
chown -R new_user /mnt/dst    # Change ownership to "new_user"

Finally unmount the destination disk
umount /mnt/dst


Ok, great, I'll try that! You said you're not sure it'll work with ntfs, but will it work with something like btrfs on the destination drive?

I didn't say that, no. I said that changing the ownership may not work with NTFS

Sorry, yes, I meant my original question but for the ownership (if changing ownership works with btrfs file systems)

Also, can I still do your Solution when the drives are not formatted the same way to begin with? Sorry, I'm new to Linux Systems if you couldn't tell

Oh I see. On any Linux-native filesystem, which includes BTRFS, you can change ownerships with chown

I've "played safe" with the arguments for rsync. The copy will keep timestamps but neither owner/group nor permissions. If you want to keep those, use -a instead of -rt

In the process of adding the new hdd to my system, I accidentally destroyed it. RIP 300 dollars

There are two ways to copy drives like this:

You can clone them with a tool like dd (there are probably better tools for this), and this will require a partition if you want to use it.  Technically, you could dd it to a file, but I don't see this as different than just a partition, you still would have to mount it separately.
You can instead do a file by file copy, preserving the existing directory structure,but merging it all into one partition.  Any of the tools cp rsync tar or many many others can do this.


There are definitely better tools than dd. Even cat is better

So you mean there has to be a partition-like System? I have some programs installed to those drives and I don't know if those installs would still works after a file by file copy (or just copying the entire thing over back in Windows)

Windows does things very differently.  You can't compare.   Windows is focused on the registry and moving things around breaks the registry.  Linux focuses on the directory hierarchy, and you can split subtrees into partitions or merge it and it won't matter.
